# Remove non unique objects between two lists

Tags: c#, list, linq, equality

I have two lists of objects and I want to remove **all** appearances of the **2nd lists**' objects in my **1st list**. Basically, get all unique values in the **1st list** relative to the **2nd list** (the lists themselves do not have duplicates within them). Another way to phrase this question is: how can I use List functions on my custom List. I've read around and people are suggesting overriding the Equals function, which I've done but it hasn't helped me. What I currently have:

`filteredEntries` and `actuallyFilteredEntries` are identical to start off, `entries` is an independent list. (I tried using `actuallyFilteredEntries`as basically a copy of `filteredEntries` where I can remove entries or manipulate the data in other ways.

```
for (int i = 0; i < entries.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < filteredEntries.Count; j++)
    {
        if (filteredEntries[j].Equals(entries[i]))
        {
            duplicateCount++;
            // prints false
            Console.WriteLine(actuallyFilteredEntries.Remove(filteredEntries[j]));

        }
    }
}
```

this is how I'd like it to work, but apparently you have to use the same object in the `Remove()` f.e. `actuallyFilteredEntries.Remove(actuallyFilteredEntries[j])`. The problem with this is, I run into an index out of bounds error.

I also tried a LINQ approach to no avail.

```
var etc = actuallyFilteredEntries.Except(entries);
```

expected result: I'm left with a list of unique values, reality: (it saves all `actuallyFilteredEntries` without throwing out any `entries`).

I'll add my `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` method overrides, maybe there's some mistakes in them that I didn't manage to find:

```
public bool Equals(Entry entry)
{
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(entry, null))
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (this.GetType() != entry.GetType())
        return false;

    return (Desired_due_date == entry.Desired_due_date) && (Order_number== entry.Order_number) && (Series_number == entry.Series_number)
        && (Product_name == entry.Product_name) && (Product_code == entry.Product_code) && (ProcessesID== entry.ProcessesID)
        && (Ordered_amount== entry.Ordered_amount) && (Amount_made== entry.Amount_made) && (Start_date== entry.Start_date);
}
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return this.Desired_due_date.GetHashCode() ^ this.Order_number.GetHashCode() ^ this.Series_number.GetHashCode() ^ this.Product_name.GetHashCode()
        ^ this.Product_code.GetHashCode() ^ this.ProcessesID.GetHashCode() ^ this.Ordered_amount.GetHashCode() ^ this.Amount_made.GetHashCode()
        ^ this.Start_date.GetHashCode();
}
```

Any help or ideas are appreciated, doesn't matter how I do it (efficiency etc), I just need a unique list out of two.

Comment: Is it possible that while the objects are in the lists, you´re modifiying any of the attributes provided to the hash-function?

Comment: Do you also need to override the `Equals(Object obj)` method?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Yes I was missing that. Don't know yet if it fixed the issue completely but looks good so far, testing it, thanks.

Comment: probably the better idea is to write an extension for the class other than overwriting existing method

Comment: I think this would benefit of unit testing since this would break it down into separate problems. 1. Do your equals method work? 2. Does list.Remove remove items if they are equal? 3. Does the above work when placed into a loop?

Comment: Also, make sure you are implementing `IEquatable<T>`. Priority of equality is something like this. 1: Explicit IEqualityComparer argument 2: IEquatable<T>.Equals, 3. Object.Equals 4. ReferenceEquals or automatic value equality.

Comment: Please share sample inputs and _exact_ expected results.

Answer (score 0):

`var etc = actuallyFilteredEntries.Union(entries)`

The documentation for which can be found here: [.Union MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.union?view=net-5.0)

> Returns
> IEnumerable
> An IEnumerable that contains the elements from both input sequences, excluding duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the LINQ Union Operator, you can achieve it.
Please check the below code.

```
List<string> objList_1 = new List<string>() {"A","B","C","D" };
List<string> objList_2 = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "E", "F" };
var vUniqueList = objList_1.Intersect(objList_2).ToList();

======OutPut ============
"A"
"B"
```

If you want only Unique value from the two list then please check following code

```
var result = objList_1.Except(objList_2).Concat(objList_2.Except(objList_1)).ToList();

====Output=======
"C"
"D"
"E"
"F"
```

Comment: Also stackoverflow supports markdown, it makes easier to format answer - check out  formatting [manual](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: And again  - no need to add images here)

Answer (score 0):

Answer without LINQ:

```cs
var seen = new HashSet<T>(filteredEntries);
for (var i = 0; i < entries.Count; i++)
{
  if (seen.Contains(entries[i]))
  {
    entries.RemoveAt(i);
    i--;
  }
}
```